# [elf]list functions per c file

Tags: c, elf

Is there a nice and simple way to list all functions in an elf file per object file?
Something like:
tool.exe [params] elf_file
Output should be like this:
Obj1.o:
fct1
fct2
etc.

I tried tools like readelf, nm, objdump. There must be some combination to get that output.

Comment: If the elf has debugging symbols (compiled with -g) it will contain sections describing this information in the DWARF format.

Comment: "Must be" ? Why? The tools you have listed provide all of the information. If you want some very specific format, you could write a script for that utilizing some other command line tools.

Comment: What is wrong with nm and objdump? They give you exactly the information you are looking for (no params though, unless it is c++).  Unless the obj files are stripped. readelf can give you debug info, but you have to figure out how to interpret this, assuming the it was generated into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you have this code:

```
int a(){return 0;}
void b(int a, int b){}
int main() {b(a(),a());return 0;}
```

compile it wiht

```
gcc -g3 a.c -o a
```

On linux you can potentially use nm, or objdumbp to get info about the functions and other symbols. Here is the output of nm. Look for the `T` state:

```
tletx7-reg004[RH-7:MY-]/tmp> nm a
0000000000600e18 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000601000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000400580 R _IO_stdin_used
00000000004006f8 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000400584 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000601030 D __TMC_END__
0000000000601030 B __bss_start
0000000000601020 D __data_start
0000000000400480 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000600e10 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000601028 D __dso_handle
0000000000600e08 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000600e10 t __init_array_end
0000000000600e08 t __init_array_start
0000000000400570 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000400500 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000601030 D _edata
0000000000601038 B _end
0000000000400574 T _fini
0000000000400390 T _init
00000000004003e0 T _start
00000000004004b2 T a              <<<<<<<<<< function a
00000000004004bd T b              <<<<<<<<<< function b
0000000000601030 b completed.7311
0000000000601020 W data_start
0000000000400410 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000004004b0 t frame_dummy
00000000004004ca T main            <<<<<<<<<< function main
0000000000400440 t register_tm_clones
```

Another possibility is to use `gdb`  for *executable* files, which you can run in a batch. `info functions` show the list:

```
/tmp> gdb a
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
...
(gdb) info functions
All defined functions:

File a.c:
1:      int a();
2:      void b(int, int);
3:      int main();

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000400390  _init
0x00000000004003c0  __libc_start_main@plt
0x00000000004003d0  __gmon_start__@plt
0x00000000004003e0  _start
0x0000000000400410  deregister_tm_clones
0x0000000000400440  register_tm_clones
0x0000000000400480  __do_global_dtors_aux
0x00000000004004b0  frame_dummy
0x0000000000400500  __libc_csu_init
0x0000000000400570  __libc_csu_fini
0x0000000000400574  _fini
(gdb) q
```